# Setting the values of a model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am having a strange problem in Rails.  I want to set the value of a field in an model in Rails, but I can't do it, even in the rails console.  Observe:

```
1.9.3p393 :008 > campy = Campaign.last
  Campaign Load (0.8ms)  SELECT `campaigns`.* FROM `campaigns` ORDER BY `campaigns`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
 => #<Campaign id: 3, name: "Stuff", ..., approved_at: nil, approval_requested_at: nil> 
1.9.3p393 :009 > campy.approved_at = Time.now
 => 2013-07-01 00:54:38 +0200 
1.9.3p393 :010 > campy.save
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
 => true 
1.9.3p393 :011 > campy.approved_at
 => 2013-07-01 00:54:38 +0200 
1.9.3p393 :012 > Campaign.last.approved_at
  Campaign Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `campaigns`.* FROM `campaigns` ORDER BY `campaigns`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
 => nil 
1.9.3p393 :013 > campy = Campaign.last
  Campaign Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `campaigns`.* FROM `campaigns` ORDER BY `campaigns`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
 => #<Campaign id: 3, name: "Stuff", ..., approved_at: nil, approval_requested_at: nil> 
1.9.3p393 :014 > campy.approved_at = Time.now
 => 2013-07-01 00:55:11 +0200 
1.9.3p393 :015 > campy.save
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
 => true 
1.9.3p393 :016 > Campaign.last.approved_at
  Campaign Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `campaigns`.* FROM `campaigns` ORDER BY `campaigns`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
 => nil
```

I am trying to set the value of the last Campaign's approved_at attribute to Time.now, but it remains nil, even after I save it.  approved_at is made available via the attr_accessor function in the top of Campaign's model.  Why can't I change the value of this attribute?

Edit:

Another interesting aspect of the problem is that when I set campy.approved_at and then look up the value explicitly, I get the correct value.  However, when I look at campy as a variable, Rails still shows the value as nil

```
1.9.3p393 :027 > campy.approved_at = Time.now
 => 2013-07-01 01:19:05 +0200 
1.9.3p393 :028 > campy.save
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
 => true 
1.9.3p393 :029 > campy.approved_at
 => 2013-07-01 01:19:05 +0200 
1.9.3p393 :030 > campy
 => #<Campaign id: 3, name: "Stuff", ... , approved_at: nil, approval_requested_at: nil>
```

Comment: what about `campy.update_attribute :approved_at, Time.now`?

Comment: Can you verify that you’re actually getting the same record every time by checking its `id`?

Comment: Campaign idd is 3 for both campy and Campaign.last.  Using update attribute does not set approved_at either.

Comment: Could you add your Campaign Model source code, please? It could help in the diagnostic. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you've created `approved_at` as a virtual attribute with `attr_accessor`. I suggest you do some reading into `attr_accessor` and `attr_accessible`, but in this instance you need neither.

By specifying it as a virtual attribute it's not persisting to the database. Remove the `attr_accessor` line and you won't have any problems.

Explanation:

`attr_accessor` creates getter an setter methods for an in-memory attribute on that model. This will take precedence over the getter and setter method that are automatically generated by `ActiveRecord` for your underlying database attribute, so when you call `save`, AR doesn't think that you've updated `approved_at` because really you haven't, you've updated the virtual attribute only.

`attr_accessible` is used to allow mass assignment of particular attributes, for instance if you were passing the value as part of a hash of attributes to `create` or `new`.

Comment: However, now when I check campaign.approved_at in rspec, I get an error:  NoMethodError: undefined method `approved_at'.  Are you sure I don't need attr_accessible?

Comment: Yeah, thinking about it there may be more to this, as I'm not sure `attr_accessor` would override AR attributes. Make sure that you're database and `schema.rb` contain that attribute, you may have missed a migration or something.

Comment: The schema contains the attribute, I haven't missed a migration.

Comment: Do you have any callbacks on the `Campaign` model?

Comment: I ran rake db:test:prepare which changed the error.  I am still having an issue but I can now set the field in rails console so my original problem has been solved.  Thanks.